# Does Laravel have its own events (not user events)?

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-5.4

I'd like to run some checks on my app before any controller action is executed.
In Zend Framework 2, the framework itself is wired with internal events that you can listen to and I was wondering if Laravel has something like that too. The docs only talk about user events.

By the way, I'm currently addressing this by using a middleware on every request but I feel that for this kind of thing, events are a better fit (since I'm not modifying the request/response at all in my middleware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any comprehensive list of internal events within the documentation.  Several people have compiled lists of the internal events they've found though.  The following links may provide what you're looking for:

[Internal event list 1](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-can-i-get-a-complete-list-of-laravel-5-events?page=1) (3/4 of the way down the page)

[Internal event list 2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/l5-events-list)

[Changes to event names when upgrading to 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) (found under "Core Event Objects")